# Feedback on first Typescript code in Next.js

Tags: typescript, next.js, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I'm new to Typescript and Next.js, and wanted some feedback on this code below. Do I correctly use TS like it should? Are there any security concerns I'm not taking into account?

Also, I created a `type` object called `responseObj`, to make sure all responses are in the same format. However I'm unsure about the effectiveness of this `type` when working with multiple developers. Returning a different response is as easy as forgetting, or purposly, not making use of the type, right?

```
import Prisma from "@/lib/prisma";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { responseObj } from "@/utils/typescript/types";

const Handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<responseObj>) => {

    const {id} = req.query

    console.log(typeof id)

    if(typeof id === 'string'){
        const taskID = parseInt(id)

        if(isNaN(taskID)){
            res.status(400).json({
                success: false,
                message: "ID should be a number"
            });
            return;
        }

        Prisma
        .tasks
        .findUnique({
            where: {
                id: taskID
            }
        })
        .then(task => {
            const resObj = task ? {
                success: true,
                message: "Task found",
                item: task
            } : {
                success: false,
                message: "Task not found"
            }

            res.json(resObj)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err)
            res.json({
                success: false,
                message: "Something went wrong, try again"
            })
        })

        return
    }
    
    res.json({
        success: false,
        message: "ID should be a number",
    })

    return
    
}

export default Handler;
```

Comment: This seems a great cuestion for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Alejandro It appears to be good for Code Review as long as the code is working as intended. When I redirect Code Review user to Stack Overflow I send them to the help pages so they know what is expected of them. Would it be possible for you to redirect SO users to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and/or https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778?